# Team Foundation Server Backup Tool

Tags: tfs, sonarqube

I'm using the Team Foundation Server Administration Backup tool to backup my TFS databases.  With TFS 2015 the tool seemed to recognize and backup a non-tfs database (SonarQube).   Now with TFS 2018,   the tool does not recognize this database.
Question,  How do I get the Backup tool to recognize a non-tfs database as part of the backup set?
In 2015 the backup setttings xml that the tool generates (BackupSettings.xml) included a tag section   that included my non-tfs database  e.g.

```
  <Reporting>
    <Database Name="ReportServer">CIR-SQL-TFS18</Database>
    <Database Name="ReportServerTempDB">CIR-SQL-TFS18</Database>
    <Database Name="SonarQube">CIR-SQL-TFS18</Database>
  </Reporting>
```

In TFS2018  the SonarQube tag is not included.
thanks